# Why, in Chroma key composting, green colour is used?

Tags: optics, visible-light

In movie shootings, we observe that the [Chroma Key Composting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) method is used very widely.

Why do they only use dark green colour, what not some other like white, blue etc,

[image: Movie Studio]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for reasons why movie studios do things and not physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided says, "...chroma keying can be done with backgrounds of any color that are uniform and distinct, but green and blue backgrounds are more commonly used because they differ most distinctly in hue from most human skin colors."